# oracle sql to copy rows through to down below, excel like coping

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics

http://pastebin.com/m24c4f508

--any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need to provide a column to sort by, so that one knows what the "previous" row is. Also, you should put your question here, with some sample data. Having `INSERT`s and detailed output definition in pastebin is great once the question is clear.

Comment: Also, your INSERTs are totally messed up.

Comment: thanks for informing,corrected insert statements and ordering

Comment: Oracle does not guarantee to return the values in the order you inserted them. `ROWNUM` is assigned during the select, so sorting by it does still not ensure the order. Create some primary key to sort by.

Comment: Pastebin may be pretty, but this doesn't make the question searchable or understandable in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get status from the previous row if it is `NULL`, use `LAG`:

```
SELECT
  rn,
  device_num,
  COALESCE( status_01, LAG(status_01) OVER ( ORDER BY pri_id ) ) status_01,
  COALESCE( status_02, LAG(status_02) OVER ( ORDER BY pri_id ) ) status_02
FROM tt1
ORDER BY pri_id
```

Your example takes it from the last line where it was set, so you might need to do something like that:

```
SELECT
  rn,
  device_num,
  COALESCE( status_01, ( SELECT MAX(status_01) KEEP( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY pri_id )
                         FROM tt1 tt1_1
                         WHERE tt1_1.id < tt1.id
                         AND tt1_1.status_01 IS NOT NULL ) ) status_01,
  COALESCE( status_02, ( SELECT MAX(status_02) KEEP( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY pri_id )
                         FROM tt1 tt1_2
                         WHERE tt1_2.id < tt1.id
                         AND tt1_2.status_02 IS NOT NULL ) ) status_02
FROM tt1
ORDER BY pri_id
```

Comment: thanks second one is perfect for me

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do correctly (if there is no value for status, use the one from previous line) you should look into using **LAG** and LEAD combined with an NVL/COALESCE